# Compile Error : kFirLoggerSwizzler refrenced from

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I am getting this error :

[image]

My Pods File sdk's versions are these :

[image]

Clearly Firebase pods are greater than 5.0. Peoples are mentioning this issue was in firebase 4.0 pods only but i am still facing this .

Build active architetures only is set to No.

I removed the deprecated google pod and now my podfile.lock looks like this. But issue is still there.

[image]

Let me know if i need to add anything else.

Comment: A few issues - using the deprecated Google pod, wrong, old version of GoogleUtilities. Examine the Podfile.lock to learn more.

Comment: I removed the google pods and all others as mentioned by @PaulBeusterien . Could u look into any other possibility which might causing error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Podfile, remove the Firebase version specifier.

Alternatively, change the Firebase version specifier to lock to minor releases with `~> 5.0` instead the current locking to patch updates with `~> 5.0.0`.

It seems that not all of the Firebase components properly updated their version dependency specifiers since the Firebase 5.0.1 release.  It looks like your Podfile is locking to a 5.0.x patch release which exposes the issue for you.

If you're still having trouble, share the Podfile.

Comment: thanks @Paul for this much of specific answer. It worked for me in resolving the issue.